# Getting awkward results when trying to find largest product in array for project euler 11

Tags: c++

I am asked to find the largest product of 4 adjacent numbers horizontally, diagonally, or vertically, in a 20x20 grid for project euler problem 11. The grid can be found here:http://projecteuler.net/problem=11.

I could not find a more efficient approach than to loop over the entire array 4 times. I made a variable max that was initially set equal to 0. I then looped over the array horizontally, and found the products. If a product was greater than max, max was set to that product, etc. I did this for all 4 loops. However, my answer is wrong, and probably too big.

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main () {
int twenty_grid[20][20] =
{
    { 8,  2, 22, /* data elided since the question links to it */ },
    … 
}
int max = 0;

// Pass 1: This determines the greatest element horizontally

for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 17; ++j) { 
        // j stops at 17 to avoid a segmentation fault.
        int n = twenty_grid[i][j] * 
                twenty_grid[i][j+1] * 
                twenty_grid[i][j+2] * 
                twenty_grid[i][j+2] * 
                twenty_grid[i][j+3];

        if (n > max)
            max = n;
    }
}

// Now we do the same loop, except we do i + 1, i + 2, etc, 
// rather than j +1, j+2. This does it vertically. Pass 2:

for (int i = 0; i < 17; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; ++j) {
        int n = twenty_grid[i][j] * 
                twenty_grid[i+1][j] * 
                twenty_grid[i+2][j] * 
                twenty_grid[i+3][j];

        if (n > max) {
            max = n;
        }
    }
}

// Finally, we increment both i and j to get the diagonals.

for (int i = 0; i < 17; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; ++j) {
        int n = twenty_grid[i][j] * 
                twenty_grid[i+1][j+1] * 
                twenty_grid[i+2][j+2] * 
                twenty_grid[i+3][j+3];

        if (n > max) {
            max = n;
        }
    }
}

// For diagonals, 2 passes are needed to account for both directions.
for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
    for (int j = 3; j < 20; j++) {
        int n = twenty_grid[i][j] * 
                twenty_grid[i + 1][i -1] * 
                twenty_grid[i + 2][i -2] * 
                twenty_grid[i + 3][i -3];

        if (n > max)
            max = n;
    }
}

cout << max << endl;
return 0;
}
```

To take a look at why my answer was constantly wrong, I began to print out each individual product as it was calculated. To my surprise, many of them were negative. After checking my loops, it doesn't seem like they access any data out of the array. Could someone lead me in the right direction for fixing this code?

Comment: Your first block of code multiplies `twenty_grid[i][j+2]` twice.

Comment: Which reformatting your code for readability makes blindingly apparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found several problems.

- The first block of code multiplies `twenty_grid[i][j+2]` twice.
- In the third block of code the end condition for the inner loop should be `j < 17`.
- The last block of code uses `i` as an array index instead of `j` in three places.

It produces the correct answer after fixing these issues.